# pnputil.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, cmd, installanywhere

When i executed the command via command propmt to install the driver :

```
cd C:\Windows\System32
pnputil.exe -i -a "C:\Users\Desktop\Drivers\IPEnabled_001.inf"
```

It work fine.

```
But if i execute the command in Installanywhere tool 
It showing the error message:
pnputil.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

So could you please tell why it is showing the error message and how the reslove that error?
Thanks in advance.

Please also suggest the alternate way to install inf driver

Comment: Surely it is because you are doing this on a 64-bit install of Windows and your installer is running as a 32-bit process.  There is only a 64-bit version of pnputil.exe, you'd have to run %windir%\sysnative\pnputil.exe.  Don't try it on XP.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant, it works.

Answer (score 9):

`pnputil.exe` is on 64-bit Windows available only as 64-bit application which means there is `%SystemRoot%\System32\pnputil.exe` (x64) but no `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\pnputil.exe` (x86).

Which directory becomes current directory on using `cd C:\Windows\System32` depends on 64-bit Windows on architecture of the application which started Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe`. A 64-bit application starts really `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`, but a 32-bit application starts `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`. The reason is the Windows [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) which redirects any file access to `%SystemRoot%\System32` to the directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` on Windows x64 for x86 applications.

It is best to check for existence of this file before executing it for this task running `pnputil.exe` existing only in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` on any Windows independent on Windows architecture.

```
if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\pnputil.exe (
    set "SystemPath=%SystemRoot%\System32"
) else if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\pnputil.exe (
    set "SystemPath=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative"
) else (
    echo ERROR: Cannot find pnputil.exe to install the driver.
    echo/
    pause
    goto :EOF
)
%SystemPath%\pnputil.exe -i -a "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Drivers\IPEnabled_001.inf"
```

The first **IF** condition is true for 32-bit applications on 32-bit Windows and 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows.

The second **IF** condition is true for 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows. **Sysnative** is a special redirector for x86 applications on Windows x64. **Sysnative** does not exist for x64 applications. **Sysnative** is not a directory or a symbolic link or a hard link. So it is not possible to use `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative` as this condition is never true. It is required to check if a file exists in the redirected directory, for example with `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\*` which is only true on running currently 32-bit `cmd.exe` on 64-bit Windows.

The final **ELSE** branch is true for example on Windows XP which does not have `pnputil.exe` at all.

However, it is not recommended to use `pnputil.exe` to install drivers. Microsoft publishes for free the [Driver Package Installer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ff544842(v=vs.96)) **DPInst**. There is a 32-bit (dpinst32.exe) and a 64-bit version (dpinst64.exe). Installation of one or more drivers is very easy using the driver package installer.

Let us look on how hardware producing companies which offer also the appropriate drivers like Intel ® install drivers using Driver Package Installer.

There is usually a directory structure in a driver installer package like:

- VISTA32
- VISTA64
- WIN7-x86
- WIN7-x64
- XPx86
- XPx64

Or a directory structure like:

- VISTA

  - x86
  - x64
- WIN7

  - x86
  - x64
- XP

  - x86
  - x64

The directory structure varies from installer package to installer package, but that does not really matter and usually it is quite easy to see which driver files in which directory are for which version of Windows including architecture.

And there are additionally `dpinst32.exe` and `dpinst64.exe` being either stored in parent directory of all the subdirectories with the driver files or on just two driver directories directly in the directory containing the driver files.

Let us make the driver installation example very simple and assume there are only two driver files in a package, one for Windows x86 and one for Windows x64.

- WIN-32

  - dpinst32.exe
  - *.cat
  - *.dll
  - *.inf
  - *.sys
- WIN-64

  - dpinst64.exe
  - *.cat
  - *.dll
  - *.inf
  - *.sys

The code to install the 32-bit driver(s) in `WIN-32` on 32-bit Windows and 64-bit driver(s) in `WIN-64` on 64-bit Windows by a simple batch file executed either by 32-bit or 64-bit `cmd.exe` is very easy.

```
set "WINARCH=64"
if "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" set "WINARCH=32"
cd WIN-%WINARCH%
dpinst%WINARCH%.exe
```

The environment variable `ProgramFiles(x86)` exists only on Windows x64 which makes it very easy to determine the architecture of Windows, see also [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details). The architecture of the processor does not really matter because on a PC with an AMD 64-bit (compatible) processor can be installed nevertheless a 32-bit Windows.

`dpinst32.exe` and `dpinst64.exe` started without any option simply install all drivers found in current directory.